# agregar paginas adicionales a reporte (rdlc)

Tags: c#, reportviewer, visual-studio-2013, report

Hola amigos/as buenos días, quería consultarles lo siguiente: ¿es posible agregarle paginas a un reporte (en tiempo de diseño)?

Tengo que generar una ficha de pacientes, en la cual interactúan varias tablas de una base de datos, las consultas funcionan, pero al momento de diseñar el reporte tengo este drama, necesito que cada tabla tenga una hoja diferente en dicho reporte.

Trabajo con los reportes básicos de visual studio (.rdlc) y la verdad no he encontrado opción de hacer lo que necesito.

Saludos a todos

Answer (score 1):

La opción seria crear un reporte por tabla y para imprimir puedes llamarlos a todos, o puedes revisar las propiedades da cada Tablix [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: hola @Geek gracias por el comentario, como accediste a las propiedades? no me deja seleccionar las propiedades del Tablix con el boton derecho del mouse

Comment: eso esta raro, porque si es con boton derecho, cuida que no diga propiedades del cuadro de texto, sino propiedades del tablix

Comment: ya pude acceder a las propiedades del Tablix, pro no puedo agregar hojas adicionales, selecciono agregar un salto de pagina pero no me muestra nada

Comment: no creo que puedas añadir hojas adicionales asi nadamas, el total de hojas dependerá del tamaño del contenido y los márgenes que establezcas, quiza deberias probar con las propiedades del reportviewer